# `show tables like '*' fails in Spark SQL 1.3.0+

Tags: apache-spark-sql

We have an instance of Spark 1.2.0 that we can run the command `show tables like 'tmp*';`, using beeline connected to the thrift server port, without issue. We are testing things out against Spark 1.4.0 on the same machine, but when we run the same command on Spark 1.4.0, we get the following error:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001> show tables like 'tmp*';
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.13] failure: ``in'' expected but identifier like found

show tables like 'tmp*'
            ^ (state=,code=0)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001>
```

I pulled down Spark 1.3.0 on this machine and it gives the same error as above when running `show tables like 'tmp*'`.

Does anyone know if there is a similar command in Spark SQL 1.3.0+ that will allow the use of wild cards to return tables with a given pattern?

This was done on a machine running CDH 5.3.0. The Hive version is `Hive 0.13.1-cdh5.3.0` if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use below command on  Spark-SQL shell

```
sqlContext.tables().filter("tableName LIKE '%tmp%'").collect()
```

Comment: Thanks @new-coder, but is that `beeline` syntax? It looks like a command to be run from `spark-shell`.

Comment: Yes its for Spark-SQL. If possible can you suggest me with one of my problem with Spark-sql? Here is the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531315/null-pointer-with-streaming-rdd-to-spark-sql-data-frame-conversion)  Let me know what do you think.

Thanks.

Comment: `sqlContext`  **not found**, use @secfree's answer

Answer (score 3):

```
$ spark-shell 
scala> sql("show tables like 'tmp*'").show()
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the question, a good answer should always explain what the problem was and how this code helps.